# Trustwave scanning ( PCI DSS ) failed

Tags: security, pci-compliance

My company providing servers with PCI complains. My client did a scan (Trustwave scan) but the dispute 'SSL/TLS Weak Encryption Algorithms' was denied and they provided following information.

======
Description:
The SSL-based service running on this host appears to support the use of "weak" ciphers such as:

- Ciphers suites that have key-lengths of less than 128 bits.
- Ciphers suites using anonymous Diffie-Hellman algorithms (no authentication).
- Ciphers suites offering no encryption.
- Ciphers suites using pre-shared keys.
- Ciphers suites using RC4 or MD5

  ## Evidence: Cipher Suite: TLSv1 : RC4-SHA

My Server details:-

CLOUDLINUX 5.11 x86_64
WHM 11.52.1
SSH version : OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008.

Can somebody explain me what it is and fix for this issue?

Comment: This question would fit better in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/). But, in a nutshell: RC4 is a weak and broken, encryption algorithm, thus, you have to remove it from your OpenSSL cipher suite configuration, then you'll pass the test.

Answer (score 1):

This happned because in your Web Server you have enabled this cipher suits.
Disable all this ciphers from your web server's config file and only provide AES ciphers.
then you can also check for the cipher suits here  https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Answer (score 0):

Your https config is weak and so potentially insecure if anyone really wanted to break it.

Run your website through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and it will show all the issues with your SSL config setup which should mirror the report you got. You can probably get rid of some of the reds errors it will undoubtedly throw up and get a C grade by updating your web server config. How exactly you do this will depend on your web server which you have not listed (Apache at a guess?).

However one of your big problems is going to be your old version of OpenSSL (0.9.8) which does not support TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2. These will soon be required for PCI compliance ([though they have just pushed back the date of that](http://blog.pcisecuritystandards.org/migrating-from-ssl-and-early-tls)). It's time to update to a more modern version of OpenSSL and then configure your server to use those the more modern security settings that allows.

Upgrading OpenSSL might be tricky though and might require upgrading/reinstalling web server too. Seek professional advice on how to handle this.